# Kubernetes pod still in "ContainerCreating" status

Tags: kubernetes

I have a question about Kubernetes enviroment. I have K8s cloud and after what I add assign one Persistent volume to one pod, this pod is still in "ContainerCreating" status. This PV has assign PVC correctly. PVC is on two external GlusterFS servers with replica 2.

**PV look like this:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    definitionVersion: "20170919"
  name: tarsier-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  glusterfs:
    endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
    path: tarsier-prep
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

**PVC look like this:**

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: tarsier-pvc
  annotations:
    definitionVersion: "20170919"
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  volumeName: tarsier-pv
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  phase: Bound
```

**Pods RC look like this:**

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: xxx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xxxxx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: tarsier-pv
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: tarsier-pvc
        ...
      containers:
      - name: xxx
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tarsier-pv
          mountPath: "/shared_data/storage"
```

Kubectl describe pod xxx return no errors.

kubectl logs xxx return this:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container "xxx" in pod "xxx" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating.
```

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong or where I can find any detailed logs?
THX in advance.

Edit:
Gluster mount is mounted on Master correctly and if I manually add there any file, it is correctly duplicated on both Gluster servers

Comment: Format the configuration you pasted above first so it clearer

Comment: there doesn't appear to be an `image`  for creating the container from your config above

Comment: Hi,
THX for reply, but this is not the point. This RC is shorted. On other test enviroment it works fine. If there was no available image, there will be an error about that in kubectl describe pod xxx and Status of the pod will be "ImagePullBackoff". DO you have any other ideas?

Comment: Check the status of the pv and pvc with `kubectl describe ...`. Also check events with `kubectl get ev`. That should give you some more hints on what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank all of you. There was wrong configuration on EP. Anyway, there was not any information in all possible logs or "or kubectl describe pod xxx".

Cheers

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. What is 'EP', please advise.

Answer (score 10):

To see what is wrong, check the events:

```
kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).